# Unexpected behaviour of min python

Tags: python

The lines :

```
print min([],lambda x,y: x if x[1]>y[1] else y)
print min([(0,0)],lambda x,y: x if x[1]>y[1] else y)
print min([(0,0),(0,1)],lambda x,y: x if x[1]>y[1] else y)
```

prints

`<function <lambda> at 0x...>`

Why and how to do that right?

Comment: What are you trying to do, are you looking to use the `lambda` as a `key` - then you need to explicitly use the keyword arg `key=lambda ...`

Comment: just noticed i was thinking java like and thought of key as if it was a comparator rather then a "get key" function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `key` argument:

```
min([...], key=lambda x: x[1])
```